# How do I add a confirm AlertDialog in a Rubymotion webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, rubymotion

Using the android webview template there is an example for handling js alerts.

```
class MyWebChromeClient < Android::Webkit::WebChromeClient
  def onJsAlert(view, url, message, result)
    puts message
    result.confirm
    true
  end
end
```

How would I implement this for `confirm` with the builtin `Dialog.Builder`?

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to pass the view.context to the `Builder` and add listeners that handle the `onClick`:

```
class MyWebChromeClient < Android::Webkit::WebChromeClient
  def onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result)
    builder = Android::App::AlertDialog::Builder.new(view.context)
    builder.message = message
    builder.setPositiveButton(Android::R::String::Ok, ConfirmListener.new(result))
    builder.setNegativeButton(Android::R::String::Cancel, CancelListener.new(result))
    builder.show
    true
  end
end

class ConfirmListener
  attr_reader :result
  def initialize(result)
    @result = result
  end

  def onClick(dialog, id)
    result.confirm
  end
end

class CancelListener
  attr_reader :result
  def initialize(result)
    @result = result
  end

  def onClick(dialog, id)
    result.cancel
  end
end
```